# Como alterar um valor em uma lista de arquivos em R?

Tags: r, arquivo

Tenho um lista de arquivos, exemplo `001.R` e `002.R`. Normalmente faço:

```
for (i in c('001.R' e '002.R')){source(i)}
```

Entretanto agora há um parâmetro dentro de cada arquivo que preciso que mude. No `001.R` e `002.R` está escrito:

```
x<-1:10
if(M==TRUE){write.csv(x, file = "foo.csv")}
```

Então como definir o valor de M (`TRUE` ou `FALSE`) antes de entrar no `for`?

Comment: Ainda que seja possível fazer isso, acredito que o mais recomendado seja transformar estes scripts em funções e adicionar um argumento na função. Caso o argumento vise escrever uma tabela, eu recomendaria retornar a tabela e depois, fora da função, escrevê-la com um comando separado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escrevi dois ficheiros com os nomes dos ficheiros da pergunta. O primeiro tem

```
# '001.R'
if(M){
  print("Script 1")
}
```

e semelhante no ficheiro `'002.R'`. Nota que **não é necessário** o teste `M == TRUE` porque `M` já é ou `TRUE` ou `FALSE`. (E seria melhor, mais seguro, usar `isTRUE(M)`.)

Depois, o ciclo `for` fica assim:

```
valor <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
fich <- c('001.R', '002.R')
for (i in seq_along(fich)){
  M <- valor[i]
  source(fich[i])
}
#[1] "Script 1"
```

Ou seja, atribuo a `M` um valor antes do `source` e esse valor é usado pelo código do script porque está no `.GlobalEnv`.